# Do AWS RDS cross-region read replicas also replicate users and roles?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-replication

I have a Postgres DB set up on AWS in region X and a read replica of that DB in region Y.

I'm about to perform 2 action in my source DB in region X:

> 1. Change the password of one of the users (ALTER USER my_user WITH PASSWORD 'password').
> 2. Revoke a role from one of the users (REVOKE my_role FROM my_user).

Will that change also replicate to the replica in region Y?

I couldn't really understand whether the replication only replicates data (table contents) or also user / role definitions.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

> Will that change also replicate to the replica in region Y?

Yes, Amazon RDS read replicas are meant to be a full clone of the primary database for various reasons such as [implementing failure recovery](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ReadRepl.html#USER_ReadRepl.Promote).

Read replicas may need to be promoted to a stand-alone writeable DB instance in the case of the primary DB failing & this requires an exact copy.

Each PostgreSQL database contains a [`pg_catalog`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-CATALOG) schema (in addition to public & user-created schemas) which contains the system tables and all the built-in data types, functions, and operators. This includes the [`pg_authid`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-authid.html) system catalog (table) which contains all the roles & 'users' ('users' since they are ultimately a role with login access).

Since [Amazon RDS replicates all databases in the source DB instance](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/features/read-replicas) (and thus schemas), **any user or role changes to the source DB instance will be replicated on all read replicas**.

Comment: Hey Danny - did this answer your question?